# When I try to access the state information from the reducer, it says undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-reducer

[image]

WHile I console.log state gives me information but when I try to get state._id info shows me undefined even I didnt use async and await in my reducer

Comment: Please click the link to access the image

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You didn't get any warning on browser log?

Comment: When I select it says cannot read property of request Content undefined, No warning, so when I just write state it shows me information like below :{"_id":"607a61787d40ed4f40c14cd8","name":"sk","email":"sk@gmail.com","img":"IMG1"} but when I go inside to fetch data like state._id it gives me an error undefined no worning at all